# jQuery: replace() class name / regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to write line of jquery that finds an input that has a class that begins with "a\d" (the letter a and a number) and replace the number with another number.

This is what I have tried, does anyone notice why this would not work?

```
$('form').find('input[class^="a\d"]').replace(/a\d+/,'a22');
```

Please note: this is one line out of many, I have extracted this line because it is where I am having trouble.

Comment: I don't think the 'attribute begins with' selector works with regular expressions.  The documentation states that it"Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to do it more like this:

```
$('form').find('input[class^="a"]').attr('class', function(i,cls) {
    if( /a\d/.test( cls ) ) {
        return cls.replace(/a\d+/,'a22');
    }
});
```

When using `.attr()` to set the `class` (or any attribute), you can pass it a function which has 2 parameters. The `i` is the current index in the iteration. The `cls` is the current value of `class`.

The `return` value will be used to update the `class`. If nothing is returned, nothing will be changed.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! This works perfectly. I will use this method often!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var regExp = /(a\d+)(.*)?/;
$('form').find('input[class^="a"]').each(
    function()
    {
        var el = this;
        var className = el.replace(regExp, "a22$2");
        el.className = className;
    }
);
```